# Parse Error in php

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Bellow statement showing Parse Error

```
 echo $xmlArray[OTA_HotelAvailRS][Properties][Property][0_attr][HotelCityCode];
```

> error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']'

how to solve this?

Comment: I suspect you've got this far because you have disabled full [error reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting). Make sure you see all `E_NOTICE`'s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP assumes unquoted literals to be constants and constant names can't start with numbers. This results as `0_attr` being parsed to a number 0 followed by a constant `_attr` - which does not amke any sense.

ALWAYS quote array indices.

```
 echo $xmlArray['OTA_HotelAvailRS']['Properties']['Property']['0_attr']['HotelCityCode'];
```

Answer (score 3):

quotes missing :

```
echo $xmlArray['OTA_HotelAvailRS']['Properties']['Property']['0_attr']['HotelCityCode'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless all of those words are defined as constants, you're doing something wrong. I imagine PHP is giving the error on 0_attr, but I'm not exactly sure. Anyway, the indexes are strings, so you have to wrap them in quotes;

```
<?php
echo $xmlArray['OTA_HotelAvailRS']['Properties']['Property']['0_attr']['HotelCityCode'];
```